# Accessing files inside an unknown folder

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to iterate through files (using java) with a path like below:

D:\level1\ [variable Directory Name] \ level 3 \ goal

how can I access such a file?

thanks

here's what I'm currently using, though I was hoping for something much shorter/ efficient for this. also this codes accesses each file twice, I can't seem to understand why

```
 File[] varDirectories = new File(driveLetter+":"+File.separator+"level1"+File.separator).listFiles(new FileFilter()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isDirectory();
        }
    });
for(File dir : directories)
    {
        sfos.add(new File(driveLetter+":"+File.separator+"level1"+File.separator+dir.getName()+File.separator+"level3"+File.separator+"goal"));
    }
```

Comment: Your question is too broad, and you haven't demonstrated any effort on it

Comment: If you *don't have* the name of the directory then you *can't* iterate through the files in that directory.  If you do have the name of the directory, but part of that name is in a variable, then you can *construct* the string from that variable.  Where exactly are you stuck?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wild stab, assuming that goal is a directory not a file:

```
while(notFinished) {
  String variableDirectoryName = getDirectoryName();
  File[] files = new File("D:/level1/level2/" + variableDirectoryName + "/level3/goal").listFiles();
  for(File file : files) {
      // do whatever with the file
  }
}
```

Comment: where did getDirectoryName() come from?

Comment: I figured that'd be up to you. You said there would be a variable directory name. How is this set/determined? You need the value of the full file path to use something at the end of the full file path (obviously).

Comment: well there are several directories there with different names but after that the path stays the same, I was hoping I could just ignore this name and go inside this w/e directory name .